# Word for attributing multiple diseases to the same cause?

Tags: terminology, medical

What is the medical term for attributing multiple diseases to the same cause? I assume it is Greek, so it would pan-etiology or pan-onosis or something like that.

Comment: It is a little unclear what you actually mean - do you mean something religious like "sin causes all illnesses and death" or do you mean "Cancer can cause pain, blindness, and/or lack of bodily control, etc?" Or do you mean that "Measles, mumps and chickenpox are all cause by the same organism"?

Answer (score -1):

All the Latin- and Greek-derived words I've looked at have to do with a disease that has multiple causes, whether acting individually or in concert. I've found only one word that meets the OP's requirement—one cause as the etiology of several diseases (e.g., smoking as the/a cause of, or factor in, lung cancer, emphysema, COPD, etc.). It may disappoint.

**multi-disease** (adj., n.)

> Increased plasma homocysteine (Hcy) is a significant and independent
> risk factor for cardiovascular disease. It can cause **multi-disease
> manifestations** such as smooth muscle proliferation, premature
> occlusive vascular disease, progressive arterial stenosis, haemostatic
> changes, placental vasculopathy, spontaneous early abortion, birth
> defects, impaired cognitive function and dementia.  [Tao Huang et al.;
> "Cardiovascular pathogenesis in hyperhomocysteinemia"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/18364320/)

> ...influencing many diseases, it could be termed a **multi-disease
> factor,** acting as a common pathway to multiple and diverse
> pathological manifestations.  [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Journal_of_Epidemiology/5GA5AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%22multi-disease%20factor%22) (snippet only)
>
> ... contribute to the risk of its occurrence, but also that its
> definitive characteristic--impaired pulmonary function--may be a
> **multi-disease factor** which acts as a key component or cofactor in a number of other disorders  [ref](https://www.google.com/books/edition/American_Journal_of_Epidemiology/5GA5AAAAIAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=multi-disease%20factor) (snippet only) *American Journal of Epidemiology* Vol. 112

> Prenatal caffeine exposure (PCE) induces developmental toxicity of
> multi-organ and susceptibility to **multi-disease** in offspring. [Jing Li
> et al.; "GR/HDAC2/TGFβR1 pathway contributes to prenatal caffeine
> induced-osteoarthritis susceptibility in male adult offspring rats"](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/32199975/)